# TextBox Value is null after TextChanged

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently working on a Windows Forms Application with the .Net Framework v4.6.1.

My goal is that the user can enter his data in a DataGridViewColumnTextBox and at every TextChanged Event it should calculate a total of the entered data.

The problem is that the Value of the column's value is always null, except I delete a character from the string.

My Code looks like this:

```
public GraspForm() {
  InitializeComponent();

  this.dgvRecords.EditingControlShowing += new DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(dgvControllHandling);
}

#region - DGV Eventhandling -

/// <summary>
/// Adds an event to the second textbox from the datagridview
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
void dgvControllHandling(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e) {
  if(dgvRecords.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1) {
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)e.Control;
    tb.TextChanged += new EventHandler(CellTextboxTextChanged);
  }
}

void CellTextboxTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if(dgvRecords.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value != null) {
    dgvRecords.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value = CalculateTotal(dgvRecords.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), dgvRecords.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you torture yourself with extracting the user changes from the cells? Isn't `myDataGridView.DataSource = myList;` much more simple? Then the changes will be written back in your list entries. See also https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial

Comment: @taffer the problem is that I am not working with DataSource and that this DataGridView is here to capture data. If I would just load data in the DataGridView then I would work with DataSources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataGridView.EditingControlShowing event occurs when a control for editing a cell is showing, try to use DataGridView.CellValueChanged event to suit your needs instead.

```
public GraspForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.dgvRecords.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgvCellValueChanged);
}

private void dgvCellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        var currentRow = this.dgvRecords.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        if(currentRow.Cells[0].Value != null && currentRow.Cells[1].Value != null)
        {
            var val1 = currentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            var val2 = currentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            this.dgvRecords.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value = CalculateTotal(val1, val2);
        }
    }
}
```